# Faulting application w3wp.exe, Faulting module name: OLEAUT32.dll version: 6.2.9200

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

We got multiple IIS crash on our production server, application hosted in iis8, .net framewoek 4.5 windows 2012 server. This issue occurred frequently on our server, and all session data of the logged user will expire immediately.

Error Log:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: OLEAUT32.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108a1d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000017ac
Faulting process id: 0x7510
Faulting application start time: 0x01ced45c613df0e6
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
Report Id: 7c7d3040-4060-11e3-940e-90e2ba3693ee
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after applying Hotfix (2874752)

Answer (score 0):

Following fix works for me.

Windows update kb 2874752 will fix this issue.
Windows update Kb 2876415 include kb 2874752.

**kb 2874752: Application crashes intermittently when it tries to retrieve OLE DB connection properties in Windows Server 2012.**

See more details.
http://kbupdate.info/windows-server-2012-a.php